# D3 line/ path/ marker position

Tags: d3.js, position, marker

Say I have the following network path/ chart [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yeQS2/100/)

I have fixed radius of my bubble, which is 10 and I tell where to put the arrow head on the line -

```
.attr("refX", 27)  .attr("refY", 5)
```

Say I have different bubble sizes and if the bubble size is more than 10 obviously it hides my arrow head. Could someone please explicitly (preferably with an altered example) explain how could I efficiently check the bubble size and alter the position of the arrow head or maybe shorten the length of the line/ path/ connector and put the arrow head at the end of the line/path/ connector?

Answer (score 1):

Hey i have updated your fiddle with some code check out

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yeQS2/101/)

```
 d3.select("#arrow").attr("viewBox", "0 0 10 10")
                            .attr("refX", 27)
                            .attr("refX", function (d) { console.log( d )
                            $('circle').each(function(){
                            if($(this).attr('r')>5)
                            {
                           return d3.select(this).attr("refY",5);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                            //return some value 
                            }
                            });

                                                       })
                            .attr("refY", 5)
                            .attr("markerUnits", "strokeWidth")
                            .attr("markerWidth", 8)
                            .attr("markerHeight", 6)
                            .attr("orient", "auto")
                            .style("stroke", "#ccc")
                            .append("svg:path")
                            .attr("d", "M 0 0 L 10 5 L 0 10 z");
```

Comment: Thanks for Your answer. I understand what You're trying to do here, but for some reason the 'd' in the "refX" function is coming up as undefined. Also, do You think it would be better to mash these two functions (one that creates the arrow head and your proposed one) together ? So it would do it in one function - create and assign refX ? If yes, is that possible or do I need to create it first and then loop it like you proposed ?

Comment: You can do in either way. the d is undefined because you are not carrying the data in the function. This is the possible way to do it as far as i explored

Comment: Yeah I got thats undefined, my question should have been why is it not being carried into the function ? My apologies.

Comment: Nice question Neil Am on my way to finding a answer for that

Comment: any luck ? Ive been trying other stuff but no luck :/

Comment: sry man i forgot to leave you an option. Try .data() attribute and load your data

Comment: Could you please help out a newbie and be more specific ?